# NSArray gives NSZombie error

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsarray, nspredicate

I am trying to pass a single array object (that is a nsdictionary of several values) back to my main view.

basicly when I set the view up I parse some xml into an array of dictionaries. I then set up my tableview with one of the values inside the NSdictionary, this value is also used to set up the alphabetical scroller and section titles. (this is done in a method I created)

At the end of that method I call [self.tableView reloadData]; every thing loads up perfectly and everything displays fine.

Now what I am trying to do is set it up so that when a cell is selected, I check the value inside the cell.textlabel and use that as a predicate to check against my array of dictionaries once It finds the corresponding entry I want to pass that dictionary up to the main view with a delegate I have made.

however I am getting a error, that I think might be happening due to my reloadData.. but am not sure.
This is what my predicate looks like.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",@"MANUFACTURER",cell.textLabel.text];
            NSArray *filter = [myDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred]; //error happens here
            //check to see if the value is the correct one
            NSLog(@"My Filtered array = %@", filter);
            //once problem has been found set up the delegate here.
```

and this is the error message I receive.

```
2011-10-31 10:43:57.333 code[5812:207] *** -[__NSArrayM filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6874210
```

myDataArray is created in the NSXMLParser delegates as listed below.

//.h

```
NSMutableArray *myDataArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myDataArray;
```

//.m

```
#pragma mark - Parsing lifecycle

- (void)startTheParsingProcess:(NSData *)parserData
{

    //myDataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8]; // not even sure if this is needed as its declared later on.

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:parserData]; //parserData passed to NSXMLParser delegate which starts the parsing process 

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse]; // starts the event-driven parsing operation.
    [parser release];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Row"])
    {
        manufactureMutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:attributeDict];
    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Rows"])
    {
        myDataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    }
} 

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Row"])
    {
        [myDataArray addObject:manufactureMutableDictionary];
    }
    [manufactureMutableDictionary release];
    manufactureMutableDictionary = nil;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, also do you think I am going about passing all the values of the dictionary the right way?

Comment: Can you show us where `myDataArray` comes from?

Comment: Is the code you just added above in the same class as the `NSPredicate` code?

Comment: yep. but obviously different methods.. so being that I have declared the array in .h file is should be available to all local method aye?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an `autorelease`d array

```
myDataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
```

You have properties set up so use them e.g.

```
self.myDataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
```

or even better

```
NSMutableArray *tmpMyDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];
self.myDataArray = tmpMyDataArray; 
[tmpMyDataArray release]; tmpMyDataArray = nil;
```

Comment: ahhH!!!!! I had just been doing a whole lot of reading to find an issue I was having last week with a different memory issue created from to many retains so read all about how self. is a +1 etc... cheers for that tho! and once again I have learnt something new :)

Comment: oh also, why is the second example better than the first?

Comment: It is more explicit about when we want to free the memory. I believe (I'm happy to be corrected on this) that the autoreleased version will only free memory at the end of the current run loop. In a memory constrained device like an iOS device it's good to make sure we use our memory optimally.